# JS, jQuery Conflict.. help?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please visit the following link in IE:

http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/bxslider/dropdowntest.html

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, etc, but when in IE, you click the slide down, it creates a javascript error and will not slide back up.

If we move the bxslider JS above jquery JS, it works although it corrupts other scripts in the page on the main site.

How can we fix this as is? With jQuery above bxslider JS? What is the conflict causing this jquery error?

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Tue, 10 May 2011 12:36:46 UTC


Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 16
Char: 79850
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did u saw this function : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ ?

Comment: Further to what @Daniel said, live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question*, too. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: Posting the code would result in people having to scroll for about 3 minutes.

Comment: @Kyle: *"Relevant"* being the operative word.

Comment: @Kyle: What version(s) of IE?

Comment: MSIE 8.0 - I posted this in the question also.

Comment: How annoying the other poster now deletes his answer along with my comments !

Comment: @Kyle: LOL, so you did. :-) I'd walk through with IE8's debugger, I suspect something in bxslider is unhappy.

Comment: @422: It's perfectly correct to delete an answer that's incorrect or irrelevant, props to that user. If your comments related to the question rather than the answer, you'd want to post them here. Your comment was *"Seemingly the js from lines 10 onwards, are for the slide up / down function, so presuming you have ommitted all code, to setup this demo. Further you have ommitted the code for the bx slider. ( to drive the image slider (( as this is what bxslider does )) ) This is in answer to TJ Crowder"* (You can see deleted answers with enough rep.) I have to say I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: @422: Re *"Further you have ommitted the code for the bx slider"* He has? There's a `script` tag on line 8 of the HTML that refers to the bxslider file, and it's there. I don't think @Kyle's missed it out.

Comment: No , I mean he has ommitted to include the actual slider . which doesnt affect the performance of what he is doing. Merely pointing out.

Comment: it's working in IE8 here. incidentally, no need to have so many `$(document).ready(function() {});` blocks. You can combine them into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it seems like you're wanting, you don't actually need to load bxslider (not that this solves the js error). jQuery has a method called slideDown() and slideUp() that already does what you're trying to do on that page...

Answer (score 0):

I opened the link in IE 9, but I did't notice any error. Anyway I think the error is somewhere related to this character `\u25ba` like in `$("#setup-describe").text("More ... \u25ba");`

Try replacing it with something else.